# Eloquent Intermediate Tabel with None Standard ID Column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

While creating my database according to the eloquent standard, I ran into the problem that my *table_name* and *id* column name combined would be longer as 64 characters.

`very_long_table_name.very_long_column_name_id`

So I used a shorter column name as the foreign key in my Intermediate Table.

Migration file:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('short_id');
$table->foreign('short_id')->references('id')->on('very_long_table_name');
```

That worked fine, yet now I would like to insert a connection

Seeder.php:

```
$x->very_long_table_name()->attach($other_table_name->id);
```

I get the error:
*SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'very_long_column_name_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `very_long_table_name` (`just_an_id`, `very_long_column_name_id`) values (1, 1))*

What I would want is that it would use the column *short_id* instead of *very_long_column_name_id* to insert this, is there any cool way to fix this? or do I need to insert and query the connection manually if I keep the long names?

Comment: You omitted the most important part of your question, and that's how you're defining the relationships between `$x` (a Model of some kind) and `function very_long_table_name()` (a Relationship). You can define which `id` to use, just check the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure, something like `return $this->belongsToMany(Model::class, 'table_name', 'local_id', 'foreign_id');`

Comment: i think that is my anwser, thank you! if you type it up I'll vote you up ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Tim points out in the comments this needs to be done in the Model VeryLongTableName.php where you define the relationship:

```
public function very_long_table_name() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(Model::class, 'very_long_table_name', 'local_id', 'short_id');
}
```